# How to sign into Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, login, launchpad

Trying to sign into Ask Ubuntu using a Launchpad account. It won't let me get that far once it got me to the authentication part but none the less it fails.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of where it fails?

Comment: Also, have you tried logging on to Launchpad first (so you're already authenticated with the Launchpad SSO)?

Comment: Interestingly, AU is built on ASP.NET 3.5. And no, I don't think it runs on Mono, since the DB is MSSQL anyway and would need to run on Windows. Point being: other Ubuntu sites are not built on MS technology, and I don't know if there is even a central Kerberos server and I it would be surprising if the Stack Overflow platform had Kerberos support. I am guessing a lot here, someone help me out.